# The keyboard's keypresses are not detected

Tags: javascript, canvas, keypress

I'm wondering if my keyboard is broken, or I have problem with the code.
The code below detects if the user is pressing the "u", "d", "j", and "m" keys.

It seems impossible to recognize that all four keys are pressed at once. It can at most detect when 3 keys are pressed. I can't seem to find the problem.  I would greatly appreciate your help.

```js
var jkeypressed = false;
var ukeypressed = false;
var dkeypressed = false;
var mkeypressed = false;


function yeah() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  canvas.height = 500;
  canvas.width = 500;


  document.addEventListener("keydown", function(ev) {
    switch (ev.keyCode) {
      case 77:
        mkeypressed = true;
        break;
      case 74:
        jkeypressed = true;
        break;
      case 85:
        ukeypressed = true;
        break;
      case 68:
        dkeypressed = true;
        break;
    }
  }, false);

  document.addEventListener("keyup", function(ev) {
    switch (ev.keyCode) {
      case 77:
        mkeypressed = false;
        break;
      case 74:
        jkeypressed = false;
        break;
      case 85:
        ukeypressed = false;
        break;
      case 68:
        dkeypressed = false;
        break;
    }
  }, false);

  context.fillStyle = "#33CCFF";
  context.font = "20px Arial";
  context.fillText(dkeypressed + ' ' + jkeypressed + ' ' + ukeypressed + ' ' + mkeypressed, 300, 50);

}
var x = setInterval(yeah, 1);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: document.body.addEventListener - you forgot the body part

Comment: Thank you for replying, Dude!  I made that change, but the page still won't display all keys as "true"

Comment: I think it's your keyboard (but not necessarily broken). See http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6669/how-do-i-remove-the-limit-on-pc-keyboard-button-presses

Comment: Thank you Andrew!  That makes sense!  I guess I'll have to find a work-around for that, since I'm making a game where the player has to hold down multiple keys in one part of a level.  Thank you DUUUDE 123 and Andrew Vermie!

Comment: I submitted what it should've looked like in my answer.

Comment: You are adding event listener inside a looping function, meaning thousand s of events are called upon one key down.

Comment: It works for me, using Snow Leopard, Chrome 43, and a Logitech keyboard.

Comment: Thank you for replying, Muhammad Umer and Barmar!  I think I will change the code to detect different keys to work-around this problem.  Thank you!

Comment: i think i got it, check it out @coder452

Comment: My answer works now :)

Comment: Thanks Muhammad Umer and DUUDE 123 for the working answers!  I think it's my keyboard, as Andrew Vermie said, that is causing the problems. Through all answerers to this question, I learned something  from every one of your answers!  Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 3):

This demo is working: https://jsfiddle.net/3q9jnnp0/

Couple of things:

you gotta clear canvas to redraw at every call

only add event listener once not million times, it will crash browser.

**Also** for updating animation "Efficiently" use  `requestAnimationFrame`. It's really simple to use just pass it a function to call in looping function and invoke it once. http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/

```
var jkeypressed = false;
var ukeypressed = false;
var dkeypressed = false;
var mkeypressed = false;

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.height = 500;
canvas.width = 500;
context.fillStyle = "#33CCFF";
context.font = "20px Arial";

document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function (ev) {
    switch (ev.keyCode) {
        case 77:
            mkeypressed = true;
            break;
        case 74:
            jkeypressed = true;
            break;
        case 85:
            ukeypressed = true;
            break;
        case 68:
            dkeypressed = true;
            break;
    }
}, false);

document.body.addEventListener("keyup", function (ev) {
    switch (ev.keyCode) {
        case 77:
            mkeypressed = false;
            break;
        case 74:
            jkeypressed = false;
            break;
        case 85:
            ukeypressed = false;
            break;
        case 68:
            dkeypressed = false;
            break;
    }
}, false);


function yeah() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.fillText(dkeypressed + ' ' + jkeypressed + ' ' + ukeypressed + ' ' + mkeypressed, 300, 50);
}
var x = setInterval(yeah, 1);
```

Comment: Thank you Muhammad Umer!  Your demo is definitely more efficient than mine!  I think it's my keyboard that's the cause of the detection problems.  Again, thanks for the help!

Comment: no i wasn't detecting a change either. but then i checked what was happening, at every keydown i was getting 3003333 calls. So maybe that had to something with it.

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify your code to:
Some things that I noticed/fixed:

- script not in body
- added "keys" array to hold true/false keyCode
- cleaner updating code
  (not switch, only testing on keyup and keydown and not every
  millisecond)
- canvas not being cleared

I hope this helps :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>

   <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

    <script>

    var keys = [];

    var jkeypressed = false;
    var ukeypressed = false;
    var dkeypressed = false;
    var mkeypressed = false;

    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        canvas.height = 500;
        canvas.width = 500;
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
            context.fillStyle = "#33CCFF";
            context.font = "20px Arial";

    document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function(ev)
    {
        keys[ev.keyCode] = true;
        update();
    }, false);

    document.body.addEventListener("keyup", function(ev)
    {
        keys[ev.keyCode] = false;
        update();
    }, false);

    function update()
    {
        mkeypressed = false;
        jkeypressed = false;
        ukeypressed = false;
        dkeypressed = false;

        if (keys[77])
        {
            mkeypressed = true;
        }
        if (keys[74])
        {
            jkeypressed = true;
        }
        if (keys[85])
        {
            ukeypressed = true;
        }
        if (keys[68])
        {
            dkeypressed = true;
        }

        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        context.fillText("D: " + dkeypressed + "    J: " + jkeypressed + "   U: " + ukeypressed + "   M: " + mkeypressed,
        100, 100);
    }

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you Dude!  Thanks for showing me how to make the code more efficient!  It will really help in optimizing my game!

Comment: I'm curious, what type of game are you making and why would you need those keys in the game?